# Magento 2 where to add `<link rel=preload>`

Tags: magento2, speedoptimization

I'm doing some page speed optimization and it says that I should preload some icons.

[image]

I've got this command but I can't find where to add it, they say that It should be added to the `<head>` but I'm not sure where. I tried adding it to my default_head_blocks.xml but it broke the site:

```
<link rel="preload" href="font.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin>
```

I've been following this but they don't tell where to add it.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49674092/preloading-font-with-rel-preload
- https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/02/preload-what-is-it-good-for/#early-loading-of-fonts

Answer (score 2):

I know its too late to answer, but adding my finding to help others. I have tested this in Magento 2.4.x and below solution is working fine.

1. Create your custom theme.
2. Under Magento_Theme/layout folder create default_head_blocks.xml file.
3. Add you font by using below code:

> <font src="fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2"/>

4. Flush the cache & do static-content deploy.

Above code will automatically add  in the font. For reference you can check the Luma theme default_head_blocks.xml file.

**Note**: For example, if you want to add fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.5.0 then it will not work. It will only work with the exact filename as I mentioned above.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hei!

Have a look on this. I guess you can add that on the HTML head.

https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/design/html-head.html

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

A very quick and simple place to add preload/prefetch/preconnect directives is in: `Admin > Content > Design > Configuration > [YOUR STORE] > HTML Head > Scripts and Stylesheets`