# How to preload custom fonts in Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2, css, performance, fonts, styles

I have a custom font in my theme already added through the "web/css/source/_typography.less".

```
& when (@media-common = true) {
.lib-font-face(
    @family-name: @font-family-name__base,
    @font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/poppins/light/Poppins-Light',
    @font-weight: 300,
    @font-style: normal
);
```

I am wondering how I can add a "preload" instruction? The problem is because due less the files will be preprocessed and generated. so I can not add a hardocded path in the "head" section of my site. The path will change each time I change the css / less files on the site i.e. the "version1612984603" will change when I flush cache or recompile the less files.

Example dynamic generated link by magento for that font file

```
https://example.com/static/version1612984603/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/de_DE/fonts/poppins/light/Poppins-Light.woff2
```

Example preload instruction

```
  <head>
    <link rel="preload" as="font" href="/static/version1612984603/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/de_DE/fonts/poppins/light/Poppins-Light.woff">
  </head>
```

So how can I do this?

**Remark**: I have seen that the `<font>`feature (see [custom fonts](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/using-fonts.html)) has been added in magento 2.3.x but I can not update my installation from 2.2 to 2.3 due the incompatibiity of some extensions.

Comment: I have added my tested answer here. Hope this will help others: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/344988/45332

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by adding phtml file in head section

Step 1. Create default_head_blocks.xml file on path app\design\frontend<Vendor Name><theme name>\Magento_Theme\layout and add below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="preload.custom.font" template="Magento_Theme::html/preload_fonts.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </head>
</page>
```

Step 2. Create new preload_fonts.phtml file on path app\design\frontend<Vendor Name><theme name>\Magento_Theme\templates\html

```
<link rel="preload" as="font" href="<?= $block->getViewFileUrl('fonts/poppins/light/Poppins-Light.woff2') ?>" type="font/woff2" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: After following this answer got below error: Element 'referenceBlock': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( title, css, link, meta, script, remove, attribute, font ).

Comment: The head.additional node in the XML needs to go in between the <body> section (this is unintuitive), otherwise you will the error described above.